# How do I convert ESRI X,Y to Lat, Long for Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude, google-fusion-tables, xy

I've downloaded the data from [NYC Parking regulation](http://a841-dotweb01.nyc.gov/datafeeds/ParkingReg/Parking_Regulation_Shapefile.zip). I want to plot that on Google Maps. I use http://www.shpescape.com/ft/ to convert to Google Fusion Maps but the data is in X,Y coordinates instead of Lat, Long. How do I convert X,Y coordinates to Lat, Long? I'm using OSX.

Here's the sample data.

```
1005740.867110
243957.356623
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting coordinates to 4326 for Google Maps.](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120169/converting-coordinates-to-4326-for-google-maps)

Comment: It helps to think geographic coordinate system data as "Lon,Lat", so you don't flip the X,Y order.

Comment: Looks like NAD83 state plane New York Long Island using US survey feet, EPSG:2263.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is in LAT/LON (WGS84) but the X and Y columns are in a projected coordinate system, likely something like UTM or State Plane.

So all you have to do is create 2 new columns for the Lat and Lon, and populate them like this:

[How do I calculate the latitude and longitude of points using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/how-do-i-calculate-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-points-using-qgis)